# Right procedure to backup and RESTORE Docker named volume

Tags: docker, backup, restore, docker-volume

I'm currently looking for a procedure to create a *true* backup of a named volume in Docker and especially also the procedure to **restore** this backup as part of a DRP.

I know the question look simple but after long searches on this topic, I cannot find a relevant answer.

Since a container will (and should) not contain data, the persistent information are stored in what Docker call "Volume". Volume can be a link to a folder in the host machine. But sometimes for technical reasons (incompatibility with host File System) the data are stored in *Named Volumes*.

If I speak about a *true backup* it's because I found a lot of answers saying to attache the named volume to a container to copy its content to the host machine (or using the new option -cp). Actually this is not a backup according me because we'll lose information like UID/GID and permissions on these files. If we restore these files in another machine we cannot guarantee that will be ok and we can have security problems.

So my question is "is there a way to correctly backup a named volume with Docker ?" And especially "how to restore it in another server ?"

Comment: What I would do is - rather than back up the Docker volume - is start up the container and use the 'native' way of backing the data up. For instance logging into a PostgreSQL container and then use `pg_dump`to do a backup. Of course you need to map a part of the file system to the container so you can back the data up to somewhere outside the container. That way your backup is only dependent on your database and not on Docker's volume format - which might change.

Comment: IMHO this is a good reason to prefer host paths to named volumes: you're not "trapped" within the Docker ecosystem for basic things like backups.